# Migrating MySQL blob (image) to FileMaker container using PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell, filemaker

In searching I've found a number of other people that have tried, but none that have been successful.

Here's the problem. I want to take a bunch of images I have stored on my MySQL server in blobs and move them into FileMaker containers.

The best lead I've got is the putas command. It looks something like putas ('$Image','JPEG').

My particular application is as follows. $DataSet.Image1 is a JPEG file stored as "0xFFD8....". The data being in this format may well be the issue, but I don't know what I'd need to convert it to first.

```
$cmd.CommandText = "update Checklists set Image1 = PutAs('$($DataSet.Image1)', 'JPEG')"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

All I keep getting is syntax error, but I've tried the syntax many different ways I can't get it to go no matter what I do.

I'd very much like to see someone having success with this to post their example. Any other ideas or workarounds are welcome as well.

Edit:
Here is some extra info. Greg Lane at Skeleton Key gives this example, but I'm not sure how to translate it to PowerShell.

```
import java.sql.*; import java.io.*;
def url = "jdbc:filemaker://localhost/fmserver_sample";
def driver = "com.filemaker.jdbc.Driver";
def user = "admin";
def password = "";
System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", driver);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, user, password);
filename = "/Users/Greg/Pictures/vacation/DSC_0202.jpg";
file = new File (filename);
inputstream = new FileInputStream (filename);
sql = "INSERT INTO english_nature (ID, img) VALUES (-1, PutAs(?, 'JPEG'))";
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement ( sql );
pstatement.setBinaryStream (1, inputstream, (int)file.length ());
pstatement.execute ();
//cleanup
pstatement = null;
inputstream = null;
file = null;
connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone in the future here is how you do it.

```
$cmd.CommandText = "update Checklists set Image1 = PutAs(?, 'JPEG') where serial = '$($DataSet.serial)' AND ChecklistNumber = 1"
$cmd.Parameters.Add('?', $DataSet.Image1)
$cmd.Prepare()
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```